# Facebook API Login Error and how to set acces token

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook API is not working for me.. When I comment the line

`$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik')`;

Its throwing an error

> "The parameter app_id is required"

Else

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /mounted-storage/home122a/sub004/sc44038-VQQX/psychegames.com/test/src/base_facebook.php on line 1271"
```

My PHP CODE is

```
   <?php

 require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 $appid = 'MYAPPID',
  $appsecret = 'MYAPPSECRETID',
  $pageId = 'MYPAGEID'
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

   // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
  //
      // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

  if ($user) {
  try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e);
   $user = null;
    }
  }

            // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
        if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
       $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists'
  ));
 }

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$facebook->api('/me') is used to get the facebook id of the currently logged in user.Once you comment that line, API can't authenticate the user and so throw the error. But why you are commenting that line?

Comment: Actually i am the admin of the website and facebook fan page.I just wanna post on my fb fans page from my website rather than posting user's page. So i dont need to authenticate myself whenever i post on my page right? Hope you understand what i am trying to tell

Answer (score 0):

There is a capitalization error.

```
$appid = 'MYAPPID',
```

Should be

```
$appId = 'MYAPPID',
```

And

```
$appsecret = 'MYAPPSECRETID',
```

Should be

```
$secret = 'MYAPPSECRETID',
```

An example of how it should work can be found at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: Thanks For Contribution.Please  see the above comment and help me out

Comment: @PsycheGenie that's a completely different issue than your original question.

Comment: ya i agree.... I sorted out that problem... Please help me out in this problem... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

`// This call will always work since we are fetching public data. Replace it with 
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');`

with

`// This one..
    $userData  = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,email,friends,last_name,gender,hometown,birthday,picture,bio,timezone');`

this will help you to get user data with permission granted.

Works with Facebook SDK for PHP - API Reference (v3.2.3) And php (v5.3).